# next-auth running inside an iFrame redirect to OAuth provider running in a subdomain

Tags: redirect, iframe, oauth-2.0, next-auth

My React.JS / Next.JS application deployed at [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) is running inside an iFrame. It uses next-auth library which, when the user clicks "Sign In", will redirect to subdomain.mydomain.com However, it doesn't happen. The redirection just doesn't work. There is no errors in the browser console and no logs observed at the OAuth provider. What could be the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: How did you have the providers (e.g. GitHub, Google) run in an iFrame?